# How to change the footer in DocFX?

Tags: docfx

Just hope to change the footer copyright info, generated by DocFX.

[image: footer]

Here is what I have done:

1. Export template:

Run `docfx template export default`, get a folder `_exported_templates\default`

2. Change the footer partials:

The files I have changed are **.\partials_footer.liquid** and **.\partials\footer.tmpl.partial**

3. Use the updated template:

Run `docfx -t _exported_templates\default`.

4. Serve the site again

Run `docfx docfx.json --serve`.

But the update is not shown when I refresh the documentation page. Is there anything else I have missed?

Answer (score 11):

Try merge step 3, 4 into: `docfx -t _exported_templates\default --serve`.

Explanation: If you open the build output in `_site` after step 3, you should find the footer is actually updated. In step 4, DocFX builds the site again before serving, so finally you find the original footer because this build doesn't use your customized template.

Another quick solution is to add `_appFooter` to global metadata in `docfx.json` like:

```
"globalMetadata": {
  "_appFooter": "<span>Customized Footer</span>"
},
```

Full reserved metadata list can be found here: http://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx.exe_user_manual.html#322-reserved-metadata

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to change the model directly. In your template, create a file called `conceptual.extension.js` and use the following code:

```
exports.postTransform = function (model) {
    model._appFooter = "<span>Copyright © 2015-2017 MY COPYRIGHT<br>Generated by <strong>DocFX</strong></span>";
    return model;
}
```